# Room: How to get actual balance of a member and use it for setter method to set balance of the specific member

Tags: android, android-room

I use Android Room for my database. I have a title screen and when I click on a button there, my activity opens. The activity shows me a list of members saved in the database. My entity Member consists of first name, surname and balance. I can add new members. The user can set first name and surname, the balance is automatically set with the value 0. I do have another entity called transactions, where I can add transaction and link transactions with members.

If I add two new transactions for a member a, the member a's balance goes up. I can click on a member in my member activity, then I see additional information of the member. There, I can see the actual balance he has with a SUM() query in my DAO.

But I don't know, how to use that query to set Balance of a member. I also don't know where(in which class) I should use the set Balance method of the member class.

Can anybody help me with this? If you need any specific code, just write in the comments and I'll add it to this question. Thanks!

Entity Member:

```
@TypeConverters(Converters.class)
@Entity(tableName = "member_table")
public class Member {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "MemberID")
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "FirstName")
    private String firstname;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Surname")
    private String surname;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "MemberBalance")
    private BigDecimal balance;

    private boolean isSelected = false;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Member(String firstname, String surname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.balance = new BigDecimal(0).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

}
```

Entity Transaction:

```
@TypeConverters(Converters.class)
@Entity(tableName = "transaction_table")
public class Transaction {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "TransactionID")
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "TransactionName")
    private String transactionName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "TransactionBalance")
    private BigDecimal balance;

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTransactionName() {
        return transactionName;
    }

    public void setTransactionName(String transactionName) {
        this.transactionName = transactionName;
    }

    public Transaction(String transactionName, BigDecimal balance) {
        this.transactionName = transactionName;
        this.balance = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(balance)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    }
}
```

[image: This is my member activity where I see the list of all members. The balance is always 0.00 because I never use setBalance() method, and the balance should be the value gotten by the getBalance() method.]

[image: This is my transaction activity where I can see the list of all transactions.]

[image: This activity starts when I click on a member. Then I see the member names and below all the transactions he took part. The balance of the member here is taken with a DAO-Query: SELECT SUM(TransactionBalance)FROM member_transaction_table INNER JOIN transaction_table ON transaction_table.TransactionID = member_transaction_table.Transaction_ID WHERE member_transaction_table.Member_ID =:memberid]

First picture: This is my member activity where I see the list of all members. The balance is always 0.00 because I never use setBalance() method, and the balance should be the value gotten by the getBalance() method.

Second picture: This is my transaction activity where I can see the list of all transactions.

Third picture: This activity starts when I click on a member. Then I see the member names and below all the transactions he took part. The balance of the member here is taken with a DAO-Query: SELECT SUM(TransactionBalance)FROM member_transaction_table INNER JOIN transaction_table ON transaction_table.TransactionID = member_transaction_table.Transaction_ID WHERE member_transaction_table.Member_ID =:memberid

I can't figure out how and where to let the app calculate the transactions. The value returned by the calculations should be set with the setBalance() method.

Comment: Can you please post the source code for the @Entity member.

Comment: @Elletlar I updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by setting balance when I add a transaction. So I take the value of the transaction and simply add it to my member balance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use column `balance` in `Member` class at all as it looks like all data should be stored in this `transaction` entities. If you have to show balance for a particular `Member` you should calculate his balance every time. This approach has one major drawback it isn't effective from a performance point of view. If performance is important than having the `balance` column is a good idea, but you have to update the `Member` entity every time new `transaction` added to the system.

Comment: Your second option is the idea I want to achieve. Everytime a new transaction is set, it should calculate the new member balance and that new memberbalance should be set with the setBalance method in the class member. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Please provide `Transaction` class.

Comment: Ok, looks like you have to add 'Member' id to `Transaction` class. Then you could use SQL request like `SELECT * FROM transaction_table WHERE member_id LIKE :memberId`. You will get a list of transactions  and summing them up you will get balance for each member.

Comment: I already use a MemberTransaction class to link transactions to member. I use this query to get the balance: SELECT SUM(TransactionBalance)FROM member_transaction_table INNER JOIN transaction_table ON transaction_table.TransactionID = member_transaction_table.Transaction_ID WHERE member_transaction_table.Member_ID =:memberid

Comment: But I can only see the value that the query returns when I click on a specific member. But I can't see the balances when I have the list of all members. Could I somehow do it so that the value of the query should be set in member.setBalance()? I want to use setBalance to set the value so I can call it with the getBalance method.

Comment: I'll add pictures for better clarification.

Comment: I added pictures with a better explanation what my problem is.